# IMAP fetch of a mime part without fetching the whole message

Tags: imap

I need some help formulating an IMAP fetch command to only fetch a certain mime attachment without fetching the whole body or other attachment. Given the following bodystructure

```
(BODYSTRUCTURE (("text" "html" ("charset" "utf-8") NIL NIL "base64" 568 8 NIL NIL NIL) "mixed" ("boundary" "===============0621936444==") NIL NIL))
```

how would a fetch command for fetching the text/html part look like?
I have read Section 6.4.5 of [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.html#section-6.4.5) several times but I still don't get it. Any pointers to further examples of fetch requests for mime attachments would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head it would be something like:

```
FETCH 88 BODY.PEEK[1]
```

where 88 is the 88th message, and 1 is the body part.

Comment: 1 is not the body part but the text/html part I'm trying to fetch, each consecutive part visible in the BODYSTRUCTURE response is numbered and can be fetched this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
FETCH uid BODY.PEEK[1.2]
```

Answer (score 2):

`UID FETCH uid_of_the_mail BODY[1.2]` is the first inline attachment.    Well, for gmail, `1` for TEXT, 2-N for attachment. `1.1` for TEXT， `1.2` should for the first inline attachment, 1.N-1 should for the Nth inline attachment.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to parse bodystructure response and then find each part section string, Once you have acheived each part section string then You can fetch required part mime.

Assume that You need to fetch first  part mime  then  command should be like this

. FETCH msgno (BODY[1.MIME])